# In Transfer Learning can we change input size?

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, keras-vggface

I am using VGG16 along with its pre-saved weights. and as this VGG16 was trained on (244 * 244) dimension Images.
So can we change the input dimension to like (128 * 128)

```
baseModel = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,input_tensor=Input(shape=(128, 128, 3)))
```

To understand the scenario lets we have first layer as Conv2D in our baseModel, with filtersize (3,3) and total 16 filters, padding='valid' .

so it will output `(1 * 1 * 16)` output when input image shape is `(3 * 3 * 3)`

but when input image shape is let say `(2 * 2 * 3)` we see we can't apply `(3,3)` filter in case of valid padding. (since valid padding so we can't apply padding)

So here we will have error?
Am I missing any concept here?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the resolution of the `vgg16` model, but the width and height must be no less than `32`, as per [keras.io](http://keras.io/api/applications/vgg/)